# How can I stain a faded area of my wood floor to match the rest?

Tags: flooring

A small area in front of the patio door has lightened but the other 500 square feet of the room remains dark and beautiful. I sure don’t want to sand and refinish the entire room. Is there a way to blend a dark recoat of a compatible product on top of the aluminum oxide urethane?

Answer (score 1):

In front of the patio door seems like the perfect location for a dust mat or a small piece of carpeting.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. Any stain applied over the existing finish will obscure the grain, being semi-opaque. That will be noticeable.

Worse, you won't likely get a good sheen match. That means that while your color may be back, under interior lighting you'll see a marked difference in reflectivity.